# d3.js rewriting zoom example in version4

Tags: javascript, tree, zooming, d3.js

[Drag and Drop Example](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)

I am trying to rewrite part of this example above to use in my code, specifically this piece:

```
function centerNode(source) {
        scale = zoomListener.scale();
        x = -source.y0;
        y = -source.x0;
        x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 2;
        y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
        d3.select('g').transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
        zoomListener.scale(scale);
        zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
    }
```

However I am getting stuck since the v4 package has changed quite a bit. I wrote my zoomListener function to be

```
    var zoomListener = d3.zoom()
                 .scaleExtent([0.3,2])
                 .on("zoom", zoomed);

    function zoomed() {
       transform = d3.event.transform;
       console.log(d3.event);
         svg.attr("transform", transform);
    } 

function centerNode(source){
  t = transform;
  console.log(t);
  x = t.x*t.k; //I only want things to be centered vertically
  y = (t.y + -source.x0)*t.k + (viewerHeight)/2 ;
  svg.transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .attr("transform","translate(" + x + "," + y +")scale(" + t.k + ")");

  transform.scale(t.k); //DOES NOT WORK
  transform.translate([x, y]); //DOES NOT WORK

}
```

and I know that according to the doc things have changed and info are no longer are stored on what would be my zoomListener
[D3 V4 release note on zoom](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom) I guess I am just confused on how I am suppose to do it with the new version. The last few lines of my centerNode function don't work which has for effect that when I center the node the zooming and panning reset...

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/psogia/simplest-way-to-add-zoom-pan-on-d3-js

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So after much digging and trial and error I cam up with an answer that works pretty well for my purposes. Note that this code below is only the relevant part of my code not the whole code, certain variable were self explanatory so did not include them. **ALSO THIS IS IN VERSION 4 of d3.js.**

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
             .scaleExtent([0.3,2])
             .on("zoom", zoomed);


var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", viewerWidth)
              .attr("height", viewerHeight);

var zoomer = svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", viewerWidth)
                .attr("height", viewerHeight)
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("pointer-events", "all")
                .call(zoom);

var g = svg.append("g");

zoomer.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(150,0)); //This is to pad my svg by a 150px on the left hand side

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);//The zoom and panning is affecting my G element which is a child of SVG
}

function centerNode(source){

  t = d3.zoomTransform(zoomer.node());
  console.log(t);

  x =  t.x;
  y = source.x0;

  y = -y *t.k + viewerHeight / 2;

  g.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + t.k + ")")
   .on("end", function(){ zoomer.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(t.k))});


}
```

As per the examples for v4 on the d3.js page, I used a rectangle to apply the zoom to

> The zoom behavior is applied to an invisible rect overlaying the SVG
>   element; this ensures that it receives input, and that the pointer
>   coordinates are not affected by the zoom behavior’s transform. [Pan & Zoom Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45)

In the Center node function I am using `d3.zoomTransform(zoomer.node());` to get the current transform applied to the page. 
The purpose of this function is only to center the collapsible tree vertically not horizontally, so I am keeping the current transform.x (here `t.x`) the same.
The coordinate in my svg are flip hence why `y= source.x0`, source is a what node was clicked in my collapsible tree. ("Look to the example referenced to the top of this thread to understand what I am trying to convert to version 4)

I am apply the transformation to my G element and then I want to commit those changes to the zoom transform, to do so I use the `.on("end", function(){})` otherwise it was doing weird behavior with the transition, by doing that all it does is setting the current state of the transform.

```
zoomer.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x,y).scale(t.k))
```

This line above is applying a translation of x and y and a scale -- that is equal to what the current state -- to the identiy matrix has to get a new transform for G, i then apply it to `zoomer` which is the element I called `zoom` on earlier.

This worked like a charm for me!

Comment: I'm going through this conversion process myself, and found this helpful. But I still don't get the purpose of the added "rect" object. Perhaps because I don't understand what are "pointer coordinates" nor how they would be affected by the zoom transform.

Comment: I followed that sample, then refactored to remove the "rect". Can't see anything amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `transform.scale` and `transform.translate` returns a new transform, and modifies nothing. Therefore:

```
transform = transform.translate([x, y]).scale(k)

svg.call(zoomListener.transform, newTransform)
```

(At this point `zoomListener` is a pretty inaccurate name for this, but regardless...)

`k`, `x`, and `y` can be derived from `source`, maybe as you show, but I'm not sure, because I don't know what `source` is. But to me, `t.x*t.k` looks suspicious, because it's multiplying the existing transforms x by its scale. Seems like it would cause a feedback loop.

For more into about the zoom in v4, check out [this related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534875/can-i-use-zoom-translateby-to-set-an-initial-pan), or [this example by mbostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b783fbb2e673561d214e09c7fb5cedee) demonstrating programmatic control over the zoom transform of an element (canvas in this case) and includes transitions.

Comment: source is where the event is coming from in the tree from the example I pointed to above..

Comment: @Yourinium right, but I don't know the terms in which `source.x0` and `source.y0` are defined. Like are they lat/lng pairs or pixels? I'm guessing pixels. Anyway, I'm working on a similar conversion myself, so might have more insight later...

Comment: @Yourinium I discovered that the order of transformation matters a lot when  working with the new `zoomTransform` object. Specifically, `translate()` should come before `scale()`, otherwise the translation internally gets multiplied by the scale. I modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Good to know. Yes the source.x0 and source.y0 are from an svg coordinate system, so in pixels. The x0 would be equivalent to the y coordinate and y0 to the x coordinate for the d3 translate

Comment: Also when i use d3.zoomTransform(node) function all I get is the identity matrix, I've zoom and panned and then I've tried `d3.zoomTransform(zoom)` `d3.zoomTransform(zoom, svg)` and `d3.zoomTransform(svg)` in the console and it's always` k:1 x;0 y:0`, I am unsure as to how to use that function as to get the current transform. Do you have any insight on that? @meetamit

Comment: `d3.zoomTransform(d3.select("svg").node())` is how the zoomTransform function can be used outside of the event listener or d3.event.transform (or equivalently d3.zoomTransform(this)) inside the listener. @meetamit