# Can I use zoom.translateBy to set an initial pan?

Tags: d3.js

I've got something like

```
zoomable
  .call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on('zoom', handleZoom))
```

I can't seem to call translateBy directly on the zoom behavior as is, is there some other way to apply translateBy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This assumes you're using d3 v4**

Here's how the zoom behavior is initialized in [this relevant example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b783fbb2e673561d214e09c7fb5cedee)

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", zoomed)

canvas
  .call(zoom.transform, transform)
```

To demystify a bit, the last line could be also written like this:

```
zoom.transform(canvas, transform)
```

`transform` is a function, supplied by you. Since this function is called and its returned value is used, you could also rewrite it like this:

```
zoom.transform(canvas, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(...) /* and .scale(...) etc */)
```

That's the lowest level way to apply a transform.

For convenience, instead of `zoom.transform`, you can more simply use `zoom.translateBy`, (which internally calls `zoom.transform` like above)

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('zoom', handleZoom)

zoomable.call(zoom.translateBy, initialX, initialY)
```

Or alternatively, the last line could be rewritten:

```
zoom.translateBy(zoomable, initialX, initialY)
```

In both cases, `zoomable` is involved, because `zoom` doesn't maintain its own state of translation and scale. That state is stored on the element  being transformed, i.e. `zoomable`.

Comment: How would one use the zoomTransform function from v4? [link] (https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom-transforms) @meetamit

Answer (score 0):

And this is how you would apply relative translations and zoom afterwords, in this example I am using [Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) to attach keyboard events to allow zooming and panning.

```
transform = d3.zoomTransform(zoomable.node());

Mousetrap.bind(['=', '+', 'pageup'], function() {
    zoomable.call(zoom).call(zoom.scaleTo, transform.k << 1);
});
Mousetrap.bind(['-', 'pagedown'], function() {
    zoomable.call(zoom).call(zoom.scaleTo, transform.k >> 1);
});

Mousetrap.bind(['down'], function() {
    zoomable
        .call(zoom)
        .call(zoom.translateBy, 
            0, // / transform.k, 
            -50 / transform.k
        ); 
});
Mousetrap.bind(['up'], function() {
    zoomable
        .call(zoom)
        .call(zoom.translateBy, 
            0,
            +50 / transform.k
        ); 
});
Mousetrap.bind(['left'], function() {
    zoomable
        .call(zoom)
        .call(zoom.translateBy, 
            +50 / transform.k, 
            0
        ); 
});
Mousetrap.bind(['right'], function() {
    zoomable
        .call(zoom)
        .call(zoom.translateBy, 
            -50 / transform.k, 
            0
        ); 
});
```