# Programmatically change initial pan state d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I define a zoom function:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
            });
```

and call it on this `svg` variable:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
        + width/10 + "," + height/2 + ")");
```

(where width and height happen to be the size of the screen).

This works great, *except for the first time the user zooms*. The zoom state is still at the origin, as opposed to the `width/10` and `height/2` translation.

How do I change the zoom state programmatically to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just after writing this I found a very [helpful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538395/3511819)

What worked for me was this:

```
d3.select('svg').call(zoom.translateBy, width/10, height/2);
```